# Trying to print the floor of the expected value (mean) of the subarray from L to R

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, compiler-errors

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*; 

class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
        int n = s.nextInt(); // the number of elements in an aray
        int q = s.nextInt(); // number of queries for l and r
        int l, r;
        int e;

        ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        // get the array
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            e = s.nextInt();
            a.add(e);
        }

        // loop for number of queries
        for(int j = 0; j < q; j++) {
            l = s.nextInt();
            r = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(findmean(a, l, r));
        }
    }

    static int findmean(ArrayList a, int l, int r) {
        int sum = 0, count = 0;
        for(int i = l; i < r; i++) {
            sum += a.get(i);
            count++;
            return sum;
        }

        int mean = (int)Floor.Math(sum / count);
        return mean;
    }
}
```

And I am facing this :
**error**: bad operand types for binary operator '+' sum+=a.get(i); ^ first type: int second type: Object

What I am trying to do is, get the size of the elements and the number of queries(range l and r) and then find the floor mean of the values by passing the values to findmean and the returning the mean value.

The error is when I try to add the values of ArrayList in findmean function, kindly help. I wanted to try with ArrayList instead of Arrays, or kindly suggest which is a good approach.

Cheers

Comment: You have `ArrayList a`. You need `ArrayList<Integer> a`.

Comment: And it should be `Math.floor`, not `Floor.Math`

Comment: thank you so much both of you, it worked, but it takes almost  seconds to execute the above code, any possible way to cut down the execution time to 2 seconds ?

Comment: The time spent in the computational part of this code is insignificant compared to the I/O time, which is mostly spent waiting for input. But I don't know why `return sum` is inside the loop. You can't possibly be getting correct results with that. Time to tune when you are.

Comment: worked !!!!! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `ArrayList<Integer> a` instead of `ArrayList a`

   Function doesn't know the type of arraylist. You have to tell the type you are using.
2. Use `Math.floor(sum / count)` instead of `Floor.Math(sum / count)`
3. Why are you returning sum in the for loop? It is meaningless. Remove that line.

You are good to go.

Comment: but for this input 
n =5, q= 3,
array = [1 2 3 4 5]
and Range (l r)
(1 3)
(2 4)
(2 5)

EXPECTED OUTPUT is 
2 
3
3

My OUTPUT IS 
2
3
4

Comment: output is true (l r)(2 5) calculates mean of 3, 4, 5. So (3+4+5) / 3 = 4

Comment: so my output is correct and the expected output is wrong?

Comment: With this algorithm, yes, output is correct. I don't know what you want exactly. What is `l` and `r` here? Are they included or excluded? Do they represent indices or starting and ending numbers? Make sure everything is clear and try again =)

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/play-with-numbers-2/

Comment: the above comment has the question, let me know if I am understanding something wrong

Answer (score -1):

+= is applicable on primitive types. By unboxing Integer to int.
 sum+= (int)a.get(i);